# How to separate legs which are joint?

Tags: modeling

[image]

That's the cat I have made with Blender. I have a problem because its legs are joint but I want to separate them and I don't want to obtain a hole in between.

What can I do if I don't want to remake my cat from the beginning?

Comment: Hello and welcome Théo. It will be easier to find a way to help you if you upload your blend file. You can do it using this link: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 4):

Select edges you want to separate and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and chose *Edge Split*.

Then move legs apart manually by selecting faces and moving them.

Then fill inner faces <kbd>F</kbd>.

[image]

If you are using *Mirror* modifier uncheck the *Merge* option, move legs apart, then check *Merge* on again.